# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes when watching youtube videos

Tags: 14.04, video, freeze, browser, youtube

When I watch videos on YouTube, the computer starts freezing. Sometimes it unfreezes after 10 seconds or so, but sometimes it doesn't. It happens both in Firefox and Chromium, although in Chromium it's not as bad.

I searched through this question and none of the solutions I read about worked for me. Freezing still happens.

How do I solve it?

EDIT: Here's an output of *lspci*

```
variecs@variecs-N550JV:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11cd
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11cd
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

EDIT 2: turns out it was a NVIDIA driver issue, reinstalling it helped fix it.

Comment: In what kind of situation it happens? For me, it happens sometimes when I try to exit fullscreen mode.

Comment: it happens even if i watch it in windowed mode, and is in no way related to switching between fullscreen and windowed mode. It just happens periodically by itself.

Comment: What happens when you turn off hardware acceleration at the bottom of Chromium's advanced settings? Does that fix the problem?

Comment: No, turning off hardware acceleration doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: added lspci output

Comment: See my answer. A driver is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a driver for your Nvidia adapter.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adobe Flash player, you should know that Adobe Flash Player support and updates for linux platform has been stopped.

you should disable Flash plugin and try html5 video players. fortunately youtube support html5 video.

To disable Flash Plugin you can do as follow:

```
    Press CTRL+SHIFT+A
    Go to the PLUGIN section, and disable Shockwave flash player.
    Reload the Youtube video. Now It will use HTML 5 player to play it.
```

Comment: It seems like i already play it on HTML5. It has "About HTML5" item

Comment: Also, what if OP needs flash? Many sites still use it.

Comment: It should be added as well that Chrome (not Chromium) on Linux includes the latest Flash player, updated the same as the Windows version (version 21 now versus Linux's 11).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem from time to time and what usually works, is to either use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or if you have workspaces enabled, switching to another one using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> or something. Then kill the flash-plugin and you should be fine.