# Ubuntu doesn't respond after playing YouTube video on Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, video

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS. The laptop never respond, if I play any video on YouTube on Chrome Browser for 15-20 minutes duration. Once it doesn't respond to keyboard and mouse pad, it starts playing the last sound in an infinite loop. Since, the laptop doesn't respond to any activity (keyboard and mouse), I have to forcefully shut it down by pressing the power button for a while. I have noticed that the right bottom side heats up while it doesn't respond.

I found similar questions on Google but they somehow are not relevant here-

- [Fresh installation of NVidia drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/752234/569883)
- [Chrome version issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/578442/569883)

The laptop has following specifications-

- CPU: Intel Pentium N3700 @ 1.60 GHz
- CPU Speed: 1600 MHz
- L1 Cache: 224 KB
- L2 Cache: 2048 KB
- Memory: 4096 MB DDR3 1600 MHz
- Secondary Storage: SanDisk Z400s 2.5 7MM 128 GB SSD

Below are the Chrome Browser specific details-

- Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)
- Adobe Flash Player - Version: 22.0.0.209
- Shockwave Flash 22.0 r0

Comment: Does this occur when playing YouTube videos on any other browser (such as Firefox)?

Comment: @fakedad: I use Firefox rarely. Let me check it now. I will get back to you with the details soon.

Comment: @fakedad: its happening in Firefox too.