# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Freeze after out of fullscreen mode (YouTube, each others)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, fullscreen, video-player

I have a bug:
When I watch some video on YouTube or each other site in FullScreen mode - and then when I exit from this fullscreen - I have freeze of my computer. Sound is still working (video is playing forward), but image stop. And my computer has no some react on my each actions...

Computer:
Lenovo B570e, Intel® Celeron(R) CPU B800 @ 1.50GHz × 2, 8GB.

Browsers: 
Both - Chrome and FireFox

Please, help with it, I totally tired to find some solution for that *** bug...

And sorry for my English.

P.S. Suspicion on 'Flash player' after some tests.
P.S.S. Tried to change the graphics driver - did not help (almost broke the system)

Comment: I have had this happen on me a lot in the past, when I used an older computer. This stopped happening when I upgraded it to a newer processor, and I think it could be related to that. I wasn't able to find a solution to it while I had it though.

Comment: Just before I had 14.04 ubuntu - also a lot of bugs, but fullscreen is working perfect. Then I broke my ubuntu (tried to install PHP7 :D ) and reinstall new version to 16.04. And now I need "hard off" my computer after fullscreen in 30% cases... Thanks for your comment, but I still need some help :D

Comment: Good luck and I hope you manage to solve it!

Comment: At first glance it's help me - https://askubuntu.com/questions/751514/ubuntu-14-04-freezes-when-watching-youtube-videos  

Will test more, but I think, that it's perfect solution :)

Comment: Good deal dude. When this happened  to me I had only intel graphics, but good that you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. In my case it was caused by CPU overlap (one of core reached 100% for a while and swap was full). There was two solutions that worked for me:

1. Enlarge swap: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space)
2. Set CPU max usage for all CPU cores any lower than 100% (e.g. 80%) or set CPU max usage for just Google Chrome/Firefox lower than 100%: [2](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i just solved that

**just upgrade your browses and OS**

if your problem is solved then don't read the text bellow

**and if that dose not work follow thebellow steps**

this problem mostly happens  with  Chrome version 49 and some other older chromium version . Below is a workaround that will solve the problem until Chrome fixes this bug.

1.If compizconfig-settings-manager is not installed, install it by

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

2.typing ccsm from the terminal and Launch compizconfig-settings-manager 
3.Double click and  open the Composite plugin
4.Add & !(class=google-chrome)&!(class=Firefox)or at the end of the Unredirect Match text box

5.Close the settings manager.

but trust me in my case i just upgraded my os and browser and bug was solved.but during search i also found this method on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=550091#c43

please go click the above link

and sorry for my English! please comment if this dose not work
[i hope this helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF3X9.png)

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer! While I fixed it by https://askubuntu.com/questions/751514/ubuntu-14-04-freezes-when-watching-youtube-videos , but need to test more.  If something goes wrong - will try your solution, just here ubuntu and it's easy to break :D

Comment: your welcome.but you should visit the link provided in the the answer.i solved my problem from their.